# how to highlight text containing variable character (e.g. ', %, $, numbers)

Tags: php

I have a code that highlights a phrase. It works when the phrase is just words without variable symbol ($), numbers and symbols such as(',*,$,). Below is my code.  So what should I do to highlight the exact phrase?

```
if (!empty($_GET['gid'])) {
    function highlightWords($string, $words)
    {
        $string = str_ireplace($words, '<span class="highlight_word">'.$words.'</span>', $string);
        /*** return the highlighted string ***/
        return $string;
    }

    /*** example usage ***/
    $string = file_get_contents('referencefiles/Microsoft.txt', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
    $words = 'Paper August 2003'; 

    /*** highlight the words ***/
    $string = highlightWords($string, $words);
    echo $string; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of the meta-characters in the pattern string need to be escaped.
Please check http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.regex.php

Comment: I'm sorry. i just beginner in PHP. can u give an example? is it like this      $words = preg_match('/^[A-Z_ -]*$/', 'Paper August 2003');   ?

Comment: Use backslashes for escaping regex meta characters such as * $   example: preg_match('\*', $string);

Answer (score 0):

Will this help:

```
function highlight_matches($find_text, $text) {
  return preg_replace("/($find_text)/i", '$1', $text);
}
echo highlight_matches($string, $words);
```